# Typescript cannot find name from imported constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a constructor that is imported from another module, but Typescript complains that it cannot find the name, despite it being clearly in scope. A small example:

```js
import {
  MIDIEvents, IMIDIChannelEvent, MIDIEventType,
} from "@thayes/midi-tools";

const {
  NoteOnEvent,
} = MIDIEvents;

console.log({
  NoteOnEvent,
});

const ev:IMIDIChannelEvent = {
  channel: 1,
  type: MIDIEventType.NoteOn,
};

console.log(
  (ev as NoteOnEvent).channel
);
```

When I try to compile (or run with `ts-node`), I get this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
test.ts(20,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NoteOnEvent'.
```

If I comment the last `console.log()` line out, the console does properly log out that `NoteOnEvent` as the class constructor. It seems like only the type assertion cannot find the name. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have a *value* named `NoteOnEvent` here, but no *type* with this name in scope. The `const` line won't destructure out a type; you can write

```
type NoteOnEvent = MIDIEvents.NoteOnEvent;
```

assuming that type actually exists

Comment: When I do that, I get `Cannot find namespace 'MIDIEvents'.` (`MIDIEvents` is an object).